# Top Level Domain Will Not Load, Only Subdomains Will Load

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have posted about this problem before and temporarily though that I solved it but updating my dns server via dnsmasq, but that solution seems to have simply stopped working.

Problem.

`example.com`  will **NOT** connect in any browser  (http/https)
`www.example.com`    connects without problem   (http/https)
`subdomain.example.com` connects without any problem   (http/https)

The top level domain of any domain on my server will not locally load in any browser on my Ubuntu 20.04 install, but any subdomain of that domain loads without problems.

If I switch to windows 10 (dual-boot computer) I all 3 of the above url's without problems.  All 3 url's seem to seem load on other people's operating systems without problems as well.

Please feel free to request any information.  I ready to throw my laptop out the window, this is driving me bonkers. :-/

Comment: Can you check if DNS resolves correctly with `dig examle.com`? BTW: A "top level domain" is `com`, `net`, `org`... `example.com` is just called a "domain"

Comment: @Virsacer  THANK YOU.. I don't know why I didn't run a dig command earlier...  silly mistake..  I used Timeshift to rollback my machine to "a long time" and it also restored an old "/etc/hosts" file that pointed example.com at a dead vbox VDI ip address.. therefore example.com was resolving locally to nowhere... meanwhile subdomain.example.com was correctly resolving to the web because it wasn't in the hosts file.... Tip Much Appreciated.. :-)